# Reading a CSV file in R in a Function

Tags: r, forecasting

I have a question that I can't seem to find the answer anywhere online.  I apologize if it's already been answered, but here goes.  I've written a script in R that will go through the process of forecasting for me, and returning the best point forecast based on cross validation and other criteria.  I'm wanting to save this script as a function, that way I don't have to use the full script every time I go to forecast.  The basic set up of my script is the following:

```
output <- read.csv("C:/Users/data.csv", header = T)
colnames(output)
month_count = length(output[,1]) ##used in calculations throughout code
current_year = output[1,1]
current_month = output[1,2]
months = 5 #months to forecast out


m = 0
data <- ts(output[,3][c(1:(month_count-m))],
frequency = 12, start = c(current_year,current_month))
#runs all the other steps from here on
```

The function that I'm writing will looking like this where it takes various inputs and then runs the script and prints back my forecasts

```
forecastMe = function(sourcefile,months,m)
  {
            #runs the data prints out the result
  }
```

The problem I'm having is I want to be able to enter a directory and file name such as C:/Users/documents/data1.csv into the function (for the sourcefile part) and for it pick that up at this step of my R script.

```
output <- read.csv("C:/Users/sourcefile.csv", header = T)
```

I can't seem to find a way to get it to do it right.  Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: What is the problem that you're running into exactly? I don't see anything wrong here.

Comment: So I want to run the function like this forecastMe(C:/users/documents/data.csv, 5, 10), but it won't put that first string into the read.csv line later on.  Should I create a line  such as file = "c:/users/documents/data.csv" and then run it as forecastMe(file,5,10)?

Comment: Just replace `"C:/Users/data.csv"` with `sourcefile` in the body of your function, then delete the declartion of `months` and `m` because you're passing them through the function call.

Comment: So that is now working, but I'm now getting the error Error in ts(x) : object is not a matrix

Answer (score 1):

So...

```
function(sourcefile, etc) {
  output <- read.csv(sourcefile, header = T)
  etc
}
```

...that? I don't really see what you're asking exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there.  All you have to do is replace your constants with the variable names you want to pass to the function and delete your declarations you don't need anymore.

```
forecastMe = function(sourcefile,months,m)   {

     output <- read.csv(sourcefile, header = T)
     colnames(output)
     month_count = length(output[,1]) ##used in calculations throughout code
     current_year = output[1,1]
     current_month = output[1,2]

     data <- ts(output[,3][c(1:(month_count-m))],
     frequency = 12, start = c(current_year,current_month))
     #runs all the other steps from here on
  }
```

Comment: So this is basically what I have going now, but the problem I'm getting is an error with the forecasting model ar.ols().  When I read the data through the function like I've set up, it's giving me the error  Error in ts(x) : 'ts' object must have one or more observations or another one  Error in ts(x) : object is not a matrix..all of the other forecasting methods I'm using work such as Arima, ets, holtwinters.

Comment: all the other forecasting methods work* but ar.ols is giving me problems